# Ubuntu 17.10 persistence of folder bookmarks

Tags: nautilus, directory, bookmarks

Having an issue with persistence of folder bookmarks. On rebooting the bookmarks still appear in the left panel of the "Files" app but clicking them returns a not found error.  Any ideas?

> The folders are located in another partition of the Ubuntu HDD and also in other mounted drives. I never had such an issue with earlier versions of Ubuntu.

Comment: You are using 17.10, right?

Comment: Are those folders by any chance located in some mounted drive, which is not mounted now?

Comment: Indeed using 17.10. The folders are located in another partition of the Ubuntu HDD  and also in other mounted drives.   I never had such an issue with earlier versions of Ubuntu.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the bookmarked folders are located in another partition which is **not** mounted currently, the bookmarks won't work. If you click on a bookmark, Nautilus (aka Files) won't mount the drive automatically for you. You'll have to mount the corresponding drive separately first.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken previously Files used to hide bookmarks if the corresponding drive was unmounted. Probably that's why you didn't notice the issue.